# El getline no me funciona en este código

Tags: string

Saludos tengo un problema con el el getline en el siguiente código

```
int main(){
//Este programa calcula Indice Academico de un grupo de estudiante tanto General como parcial   

int nota,cr;//Generales

int tnota=0;//Acumulador de total Notas

int tcr=0;//Acumulador total Credito

int gcredito=0;//Acumulador de creditos

int gnota;

float ia;//Indice Academico

float gia;//Indece Academico General

string Nom_Est;

int n;//Limitador/cantidad de estudiante

int m; //Cant Asignatura /limitador

//Subir limite 1
cout<<"Por favor diga la cantidad de Estudiantes a calcular : "<<endl;
cin>>n;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++){ //1er float
    **cout<<"Diga el nombre del estudiante No."<<i+1<<endl;
    getline(cin,Nom_Est);**
    cout<<"Diga cuantas asiganturas cursa : "<<endl;
    cin>>m;
    for(int k=0;k<m;k++){
        cout<<"Diga la nota numero:  "<<k+1<<":";
        cin>>nota;
        cout<<"Diga el credito numero:  "<<k+1<<":";
        cin>>cr;
        //Proceso
        tnota+=nota*cr;
        tcr+=cr;    
    }//Ciclo e las notas y creditos

    ia=tcr>0?tnota/tcr:0;
    cout<<"El indice de "<<Nom_Est<<" Es : "<<ia<<endl;
    gnota+=tnota;
    gcredito=+tcr;
    //Reset y limpieza de acumuladores
    tnota=0;
    tcr=0;  
}//Fin del ciclo Estudiante
gia=gcredito>0?gnota/gcredito:0;
 cout<<"El indice global de todos los estudiantes es: "<<gia;
    }
```

Comment: porque pones asteriscos antes del cout? borralos, todo esta bien

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda